# Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined] - No existing solution helps

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

So I'm working on a project for a portfolio, and I'm working on a local signup that also features name, email, and some info.
After checking online, I found this tutorial: 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

The local sign-up configuration, from my understanding, is what I can play with and tweak in order to get it to work for my code.
The problem is that it doesn't work. When I try to debug, my most predominant errors are:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
>   Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined].`

This is the app.js(/server.js):

```
var express               =           require ("express");
var app                   =           express();
var mongoose              =           require("mongoose").set('debug', true);
var passport              =           require("passport");
var cookieParser          =           require('cookie-parser');
var LocalStrategy         =           require("passport-local");
var passportLocalMongoose =           require("passport-local-mongoose");
var User                  =           require("./models/user");

// REQUIRING ROUTES
var helpRoutes              =           require("./routes/help"),
    communityRoutes         =           require("./routes/community"),
    authRoutes              =           require("./routes/auth")(app, passport);

//DB
mongoose.connect(connection);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
});

//APP SETUP
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
});

//USING ROUTES
app.use("/", authRoutes)(app, passport);
app.use("/help", helpRoutes);
app.use("/community", communityRoutes);

//==============================================
//SERVER START
//============================================== 

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
  console.log('Server Started');
});
```

passport.js configuration file:

```
var passport = require('passport'), 
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    User = require("../models/user");

module.exports = function(user){

    //SERIALIZATION AND DESERIALIZATION REQUIRED FOR PERSISTENT LOGINS
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
        User.findById(id, function(err, user){
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    //LOCAL SIGNUP
    passport.use("local-signup", new LocalStrategy({
        username: "username",
        password: "password",
        passReqToCallback: true,
        session: true},
        function(req, username, password, done){
            process.nextTick(function(){
                User.findOne({"username": username}, function(err, user){
                    if(err){
                        return done(err);
                    } 
                    if(user){
                        console.log(user, 'That username is already taken.');
                    } else {
                        var newUser = new User();
                        newUser.local.username = username;
                        newUser.local.password = password;
                        newUser.save(function(err){
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                            return done(null, user);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }    
    ));
};
```

I thought that maybe it's something to do with the routing, so I pasted the configurations in the app.js file, hoping to see if that works, at least, and the errors kept popping.
This is the code I wanted to add:

```
passport.use("local-signup", new LocalStrategy({
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
    passReqToCallback: true,
    session: true},
    function(req, username, password, email, name, info, isAdmin, done){
        process.nextTick(function(){
            User.findOne({"username": username}, function(err, user){
                if(err){
                    return done(err);
                } 
                if(user){
                    console.log(user, 'That email is already taken.');
                } else {
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.local.username = username;
                    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                    newUser.local.name = name;
                    newUser.local.info = info;
                    newUser.local.isAdmin = isAdmin;
                    newUser.save(function(err){
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        return done(null, user);
                    });
```

I've searched all over here, but can't seem to find a solution, and the tutorial seems to work for others, but not me. I checked the upgrade to Express.js 4.0v, but the solution doesn't seem to lie there.

Comment: try changing `app.use("/", authRoutes)(app, passport);` to `app.use("/", authRoutes);`

Comment: The _"Route.get() requires callback functions"_ means exactly that: in your code base there's an `app.get()` (or `router.get()`; in any case, somewhere where an Express `GET` handler gets created) that gets passed an undefined argument instead of a callback function. The `indexOf` error is impossible for us to solve without posting the entire error. In both cases, try reading the stack trace that you get, these generally point towards the location in your code base where the error occured.

Comment: as to the routes - I did. for some reason it just didn't recognize the routes (the dreaded "Cannot GET").

Comment: I'll try to find the argument again, although I searched everywhere, basically, modified it 1000 times, and I can't find the missing callback function.

Comment: @ValS add the stack traces to your question, perhaps they give a clue.